# PHP reading through json

Tags: php, json

We have created some json as follows

```
{"deliveries":[{"cn":"1498","airlinetype":" Airbus A330-200 ","registration":" G-VYGK ","airline":"Thomas Cook Airlines","date":" 29. Apr 2015 "}]}
```

We are trying to loop through each delivery extracting the data to insert into the database. We ran the data through a json validator and it says everything is OK. Do we need to use json_encode to convert this as we are having problems trying to access each of the elements.
What would be the best approach to do this?

Thanks in advance
Rich

Comment: can you show us your code ?

Comment: `json_decode`  http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You want to decode the json string that you have posted.**

A quick way since you know the name of each json branch is the following

```
$json = '{"deliveries":[{"cn":"1498","airlinetype":" Airbus A330-200 ","registration":" G-VYGK ","airline":"Thomas Cook Airlines","date":" 29. Apr 2015 "}]}';
$out = json_decode($json,true);
foreach($out["deliveries"] as $deliveries) {
echo $deliveries["cn"];
echo $deliveries["airlinetype"];
echo $deliveries["registration"];
echo $deliveries["airline"];
echo $deliveries["date"];
}
```

**Check it out:** http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cfd8cdeb7f83536db4b4df74778243306c1c2d8c

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.
Works great now.

Comment: update : when we post the data from jQuery to a PHP page we echo the data and everything looks fine but the above code doesn't work although if we cut and paste the json data into a variable as above it does work. Do we need to do anything in PHP to solve this?
    $jsondata = $_POST["jsondata"]; 
    echo $jsondata;
    $out = json_decode($jsondata, true); 
    foreach($out["deliveries"] as $deliveries) {
      echo $deliveries["cn"];
      echo $deliveries["airlinetype"];
      echo $deliveries["registration"];
      echo $deliveries["airline"];
      echo $deliveries["date"];
    }

Comment: I found the answer to my problem
I had to run this json_decode( preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $jsondata), true ); to decode the string and it solved the issue
thanks to dunith - questions/2410342/php-json-decode-returns-null-with-valid-json

Answer (score 1):

You should use `json_decode()` function. Please check solution below:

```
$json = '{"deliveries":[{"cn":"1498","airlinetype":" Airbus A330-200","registration":" G-VYGK ","airline":"Thomas Cook Airlines","date":" 29. Apr 2015 "}]}';
$data = json_decode($json);
foreach($data->deliveries[0] as $field=>$value) {
    echo "{$field} = {$value}<br>";
    //*** code to write to db follows here...
}
```